# Is it possible to explode JSON array on ingestion stage?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Azure Data Explorer is receiving data through [Event Hub subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-data-event-hub-overview). The payload is compressed JSON of the type:

```json
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "why": 42,
  "data": [
    {"field1": "abc", "field2": 123},
    {"field1": "xyz", "field2": 456},
    {"field1": "pqr", "field2": 789}
  ]
}
```

I need to convert `data` into tabular format:

```
filed1 field2
-------------
abc    123
xyz    456
pqr    789
```

or even better:

```
foo    why    field1 field2
---------------------------
bar    42     abc    123
bar    42     xyz    456
bar    42     pqr    789
```

I need to create an [ingestion mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/create-ingestion-mapping-command), which is a case of [data mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/mappings#json-mapping). Looking at the path syntax, I cannot figure out how to create such a mapping.

Is it possible? If not, what is the best way to set up such a transformation during ingestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that using an update policy.

There's an example you can follow here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-json-formats?tabs=kusto-query-language#ingest-json-records-containing-arrays

Comment: Going update policy way, I need to temporarily store the array in a dynamic field of the raw table. Does 1MB limit still apply here?

Comment: yes, that's the default limit for values of type `string` and `dynamic`